# Can a background image be added to ion-alert?

Tags: html, css, typescript, ionic4

I've tried the following to add a background image to an ion-alert:

```js
.md,.ios,.wp {
    page-landing {
      .custom-alert {
        background-color: #F35E5D !important;
        background: #F35E5D  !important;
        color: red !important;
        $alert-md-background-color: #F35E5D;
        $alert-ios-background: #F35E5D;
        --background: #fff url("../../../assets/img/match.png") no-repeat center center / cover;
      }}}

ion-alert {
    --background: #fff url("../../../assets/img/match.png") no-repeat center center / cover;
}
```

```js
  async presentAlertConfirm() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'CONGRATULATIONS!',
      cssClass: 'custom-alert',
      message: '<strong></strong>!!!',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Keep searching',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: (blah) => {
          }
        }, {
          text: 'Send a message',
          handler: () => {
            return this.router.navigateByUrl('tabs/connections');
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    await alert.present();
  }
```

The .css is an example I found online that doesn't work.  Is there any way to add a background image to the alert?

Comment: which ionic version are you using?

Comment: So, a couple of things, is `page-landing` a class? If so, substitute it with `.page-landing`. Secondly, is it necessary to have nested css classes or could you just try having `custom-alert` as it's own (non-nested) section in the css?

Comment: Tried:
    .custom-alert {

        --background: #fff url("../../../assets/img/match.png") no-repeat center center / cover;
      }

and

    .custom-alert {
        ion-alert {
        
        --background: #fff url("../../../assets/img/match.png") no-repeat center center / cover;
      }
    }

neither worked

Comment: Found the answer in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687695/how-to-give-alert-controller-css-in-ionic-4

Answer (score 0):

The only available CSS option for alert is --background. So you can take help from that. Here is a little tweak to the same:

Make the following changes withing the variables.scss

```
ion-alert
{
 --background: #ffffff url("../assets/imagename.png") no-repeat center !important;
}
```

#ffffff serves as the fallback color. You may omit that.